# Allow access from specific referer only in .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website with a wordpress installation and I'm using modrewrite to display clean urls. I want the visitors that are comming from facebook to access the site , while the others redirected to other , i made one , its working , but i am not sure how to redirect the denied visitors to the other site

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www.)?facebook.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www.)?fb.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www.)?l.facebook.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www.)?goo.gl



RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: not all browsers pass the `HTTP_REFERER` header and it can also be modified by the end user so it can not be trusted. There for this is a highly unreliable way to do this.

Comment: those aren't good regexes either. other than outright faking the referer, they could do their dns as www.fb.com.othersite.example.com. should terminate your hostnames with `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteRule` should have a full URL of the one that you want to redirect to.
For example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www.)?facebook.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www.)?fb.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.non-facebook-refer.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i did that , now the site kept redirecting me to non-facebook-refer , even though the referee is facebook

Comment: I only write the non-facebook part, you need to add the other part

Comment: yes i did , where is the problem ? , check the last code please

Comment: maybe the https is the problem ?

Comment: Use php to print out the HTTP REFERER header to check if it contains facebook.com

Comment: Rewrite is order-sensetive. try to put the non-facebook conditions first. http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteRule